# How to convert r6rs macro involving syntax-case to racket?

Tags: macros, scheme, racket, read-eval-print-loop, r6rs

I am learning scheme/racket macros, and trying to make the following macro from [sweet-macros](http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/%7Emicheles/scheme/scheme9.html) work under racket 8.6.

```
#lang racket

(require (for-meta 1 srfi/1)) ; for cons* and fold-right
(provide guarded-syntax-case)

;;GUARDED-SYNTAX-CASE
(define-syntax guarded-syntax-case
  (let ((add-clause
         (lambda (clause acc)
           (syntax-case clause ()
             ((pattern skeleton . rest)
                (syntax-case #'rest ()
                  ((cond? else1 else2 ...)
                   (cons*
                    #'(pattern cond? skeleton)
                    #'(pattern (begin else1 else2 ...))
                    acc))
                  ((cond?)
                   (cons #'(pattern cond? skeleton) acc))
                  (()
                   (cons #'(pattern skeleton) acc))
                  ))))))
    (lambda (x)
      (syntax-case x ()
        ((guarded-syntax-case y (literal ...) clause ...)
         (with-syntax (((c ...) (fold-right add-clause '() #'(clause ...))))
           #'(syntax-case y (literal ...) c ...)))))))
;;END
```

The macro was written for `plt-r6rs`, but I wanted to experiment with it in the racket interpreter/REPL (, which is forbidden in racket's r6rs).

I couldn't make much progress except for adding the imports:

```
(require (for-meta 1 srfi/1))
```

Now when testing `guarded-syntax-case`, I assumed that it is similar to racket/r6rs `syntax-case` but with some added functionality. So I tested the following adapted example:

```
(syntax->datum
   (guarded-syntax-case #'(+ 1 2) ()
    [(op n1 n2) #'(- n1 n2)]))
```

but got an error:

```
. . null-list?: argument out of domain #<syntax:my-sweet.rkt:26:61 (((op n1 n2) (syntax (- n1 n2))))>
```

I couldn't figure out how to fix the error after a long time, since I am just beginning to learn macros.

*Could some one please  help explain why the macro doesn't work with racket, and how to make it work with racket?*

I can only guess that the branch:

```
              (()
               (cons #'(pattern skeleton) acc))
```

is reached in the above example. I read that different scheme implementations can handle `#'(pattern skeleton)` differently during conversion to/from syntax objects. So the `cons` here could be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

(not an answer to the question but too long for comment):

One may observe that `guarded-syntax-case` seems to be emulating
the standard R6RS *fender* option of `syntax-case`, which is
available in Racket. The `multi-define` example of using
`guarded-syntax-case` in [sweet-macros](http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/%7Emicheles/scheme/scheme10.html)
can be written:

```
#lang racket
(require test-engine/racket-tests)
        
(define-syntax multi-define
  (lambda (x)
    (syntax-case x ()
      [(_ (name ...) (value ...))                       ; pattern
       (or (= (length (syntax->datum #'(name ...)))     ; fender ("guard")
              (length (syntax->datum #'(value ...))))   ;
         (raise-syntax-error 'multi-define "Names and values do not match" #f #f
                             (list #'(name ...) #'(value ...))))
       #'(begin (define name value) ...) ])))           ; template ("skeleton")

(multi-define (a b) (1 2))
(check-expect a 1)
(check-expect b 2)

(multi-define (a b c) (1 2))

(test)
```